# video.play() occurred unhandled rejection (notallowederror) on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, stream, webrtc

using peer.js for stream video on React APP

```
  addVideoStream(video: HTMLVideoElement, stream: MediaStream) {
    video.srcObject = stream

    video?.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
      video.play()
    })
    if (this.videoGrid) this.videoGrid.append(video)
  }
```

got this error at 'video.play()'

```
the request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context
```

already I allowed permission for Audio and video on IOS.

this code works well other platforms except IOS.

I have no idea.

If I deploy then I just get black screen on IOS.

how can I fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was how video tag works in IOS with WebRTC.

used HTTPS environment(production) then add these attributes

```
if (isMobile && isSafari) {
      this.myVideo.playsInline = true
      this.myVideo.autoplay = true
    }
```

then it works.

Comment: If anyone else is having issues, iOS is adamant in rejecting video/audio that autoplays. The error is pretty cryptic. You'll need to add some user interaction before playing your media, otherwise the browser will reject.

For example, add a "play" button

Comment: thank you I will try next time when I have chance for it.